# Probability of future success when trials are dependent: In 4 draws w/o replacement, what is the probability that draws 3 & 4 will be successful?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations, hypergeometric-function

Suppose that I have a bag with 14 marbles, 9 green and 5 red. 

 Person A will first draw 2 marbles and then Person B will draw 2 marbles. 
Can I determine the probability that person B will draw 2 green marbles before I let person A draw?

> Edit: The order of events are:
>
> 1. Determine the probability that Person B will draw 2 green marbles.
> 2. Person A draws 2 marbles (unknown color)
> 3. Person B draws 2 marbles

I understand that using hypergeometric probability I can easily find the probability that person A will draw 2 green marbles

$$\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}.$$

`K = 9 ; k = 2 ; N = 14 ; n = 2`

however if I only care about person B drawing 2 green marbles, it seems to me that now `n = 4` but k could be `k = 2, k = 3, or k = 4` but it doesn't matter so long as the last 2 instances of n yield `k=2`.

Am I thinking about this in the right way? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you explain the part where you say '_(B)efore I let person $A$ draw_'? I thought person $A$ draws first.

Comment: yes, sorry that wasn't clear. The order of events would be 1) determine the probability that Person B draws 2 green. 2) Person A draws. 3) Person B draws

Comment: @user_194421 sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that there are $9$ green marbles and $5$ red marbles in the beginning. We split cases:

### Case 1: $A$ draws $2$ green marbles.

The probability of this case is
$\binom92/\binom{14}2=\frac{36}{91}$.

After $A$ draws, there would remain $7$ green marbles, $12$ marbles in total.

The probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles after that is
$\binom72/\binom{12}2=\frac{21}{66}$.

So, the probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles through this case is
$$\frac{36}{91}\cdot\frac{21}{66}\text.$$

### Case 2: $A$ draws $1$ green marble and $1$ red marble.

The probability of this case is
$\binom91\binom51/\binom{14}2=\frac{45}{91}$.

After $A$ draws, there would remain $8$ green marbles, $12$ marbles in total.

The probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles after that is
$\binom82/\binom{12}2=\frac{28}{66}$.

So, the probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles through this case is
$$\frac{45}{91}\cdot\frac{28}{66}\text.$$

### Case 3: $A$ draws $2$ red marbles.

The probability of this case is
$\binom52/\binom{14}2=\frac{10}{91}$.

After $A$ draws, there would remain $9$ green marbles, $12$ marbles in total.

The probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles after that is
$\binom92/\binom{12}2=\frac{36}{66}$.

So, the probability of $B$ drawing $2$ green marbles through this case is
$$\frac{10}{91}\cdot\frac{36}{66}\text.$$

### Total probability

So, across all cases, the probability is
$$\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{36}{91}\cdot\frac{21}{66}
+\frac{45}{91}\cdot\frac{28}{66}
+\frac{10}{91}\cdot\frac{36}{66}\right)\\
=&\frac{36\cdot21+45\cdot28+10\cdot36}{91\cdot66}\\
=&\frac{756+1260+360}{6006}\\
=&\frac{2376}{6006}\\
=&\frac{36}{91}\text.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very clear. So really its only when you know the color of one or both of person A's marbles does the probability of person B drawing 2 green differ.